# Unable to upload file to salesforce using c#

Tags: c#, salesforce, httprequest, salesforce-lightning

I am using salesforce v49.0. I wrote code to upload file(txt file) from my directory to salesforce.
I have created a folder in my salesforce account.
I am getting Bad Request while trying to upload.
Please help to find the solution or suggest any other ways to upload the file.

My Code

```
        string oauthToken = (string)loginResponse["access_token"];
        string serviceUrl = (string)loginResponse["instance_url"];
        var doc = new sfdcDocument();
        doc.Name = "DocumentbyDuke";
        doc.FolderId = "05He0000RE00CcKDERTD";
        doc.Type = "txt";
        doc.Keywords = "123";
        doc.Description = "123";
        string boundary = "----" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        var uri = serviceUrl + "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Document/";
        var req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + oauthToken);
        req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        req.Method = "POST";
        var os = req.GetRequestStream();


        // Add header for JSON part
        string body = "";
        body += "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n"; ;
        body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='entity_document'\r\n";
        body += "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n";

        // Add document object data in JSON
        body += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);


        // Add header for binary part 
        body += "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n"; ;
        body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='Body'; filename='1.txt'\r\n";
        body += "Content-Type: binary/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";


        // Add header data to request
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
        os.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        // Add file to reqeust
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\AprilFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            os.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        // Add trailer
        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        os.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        os.Close();


        // Do the post and get the response.
        WebResponse resp;

        try
        {
            resp = req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            resp = ex.Response;
        }

        //if (resp == null) return null;
        var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: I ran the Code and Captured Response from [Fiddler](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/InstallFiddler).

It is showing 

87 [{"message":"Folder ID: id value of incorrect type: *08He0000000sqweER","errorCode":"FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION","fields":["FolderId"]}] 0

Answer (score 0):

`08H`, as shown in your comment is not the Key Prefix for any type of Folder. It appears to belong to an obscure sObject called [`CleanBatchErrorLog`](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html).

`05H` corresponds to `ContentDistributionView`, which is also incorrect.

While there may be other issues, you definitely need to locate the correct folder id to store this document.